# Updating/creating Table of Contents in Word using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm new to VBA. I'm trying to update the Table of Contents in my Word document everytime I open the document, but it does not seem to update it at all.

In `ThisDocument` I've done the following:

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents(1).Update
End Sub
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is probably the use of `Document_Open` - you have to set up the event in the template, not the document you are opening. You can also use an `Auto_Open` macro. Note that `ActiveDocument` may also be part of the culprit - the document you open may not yet be the actual active document when you kick the `Document_Open` event - you may need to set a reference to the document you're opening like:

```
Dim doc As Document
set doc = Documents.Open(your path here)
doc.TablesOfContents(1).Update
```

Finally, your Macro Security settings could be disallowing anything from executing.

In all cases, have a good read of [Take Control of Microsoft Word Through Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140279(office.10).aspx) and [Running a macro automatically when a document is created, opened or closed](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/macrosvba/documentevents.htm).