# How to update the table of contents in word on Mac?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I read many other solutions available on different threads here [One is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093528/updating-creating-table-of-contents-in-word-using-vba), [another here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43695419/updating-table-of-contents-in-word), but I could not get mine to work. It is stuck. See the images below for the error it poses when running. I am totally new to this and not no idea of macros. I need to get the Table Of Contents to "Update the entire table." I add content in three different heading levels and need to update it frequently. It's tedious to go over every time for the same process repeatedly. Thank you for the help.

Edit: I need this macro to work on multiple documents, and not just one. So, a generalized one that I could add to normal.dotm would be great.

The code I entered is below.

```
Sub FieldUpdates()
Dim oStory As Range
For Each oStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    oStory.Fields.Update
    If oStory.StoryType <> wdMainTextStory Then
        While Not (oStory.NextStoryRange Is Nothing)
            Set oStory = oStory.NextStoryRange
            oStory.Fields.Update
        Wend
    End If
Next oStory
Set oStory = Nothing

Dim TOC As TableOfContents
For Each TOC In ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents
    TOC.Update
Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Edit 2: I just tried one block of code which worked. Are there any concerns I should have using this code since the document I'll be using it is important to me.

```
Sub TableOfContents()
   If ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents.Count = 1 Then _
  ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents(1).Update
End Sub
```

Comment: I removed it @BigBen; thank you for pointing that out. I corrected the way I asked the question.

Comment: The compile error is because you named a module `TableOfContents`, so rename it to something else.